# How To Remove Space From Middle Of String

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to get rid of a space.

Current Results:
P O BOX 140

Desired Results:
PO BOX 140

--This script did not work
update table
set column= replace(column, 'P O', 'PO')
from table

Comment: Is the space always the second "letter"?Give more relevant samples if not

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? Do you know there is only a single space? Do you know for sure it is a space and not some other hidden character?

Comment: Yes there is one space. More Examples:  If i have P O Box 111, I would like to remove the space from the P O to PO.

Comment: How did it not work? Incorrect results? Syntax error? Blue screen of death? Probably a syntax error if the `from table` at the end is really part of your query.

Comment: Let's hope you have no addresses like 123 Kip Owen Ave.

Comment: Melissadata.com and I hate them but they're going to be orders of magnitude better than whatever cases you stumble across

Comment: VtC as unclear because (a) you haven't explained what on earth "did not work" means (b) you haven't indicated if this is the only such pattern - can people have `P O #140`, for example? What do you want to do with `RR #1 P O BOX 140`? How about `1 Carp Ovum Drive`? Should that become `1 CarPOvum Drive`?

Comment: Is there a match on the collation sequence of the two strings being compared? Do you know its a space and not a tab or some other non-printable character?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something simple if the space is always the 2nd position....

take the left most character add the right most characters -1 for first letter and -1 for the space.

```
Select left('P O BOX 140',1) + right('P O BOX 140',len('P O BOX 140')-2) as NoO
...
WHERE UPPER(FieldText) Like 'P O%'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2a2dd/4/0

you could add some where clause limits to ensure the first character is P and the 3rd is O as well..

Comment: and that there is a space between them?

Comment: Sure; but this is a hack no matter what.  The only way to 100% quality scrub is by human eyes; and even those dumb humans make mistakes.

Comment: would appreciate understanding why the down vote.